# Meta table(s?) in Ion Auth (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm hoping to use Ion Auth for a Codeigniter application, but I'm unsure of exactly how to structure the tables appropriately.  Basically, I have a few different types of users each with different attributes.  How would one build this out with just a single meta table?

Some ideas were offered here ( [Create user roles and profiles in Codeigniter using Ion Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240059/create-user-roles-and-profiles-in-codeigniter-using-ion-auth) ) but none seem particularly elegant or ideal.  Is there a a better way?  Can I easily work with multiple meta tables (e.g. meta_type1, meta_type2, etc.) somehow?

A related issue pertains to the "identity" config parameter for login etc.  How could I have the identity be email for one user type, and username for another?

Thanks in advance for any tips/advice/ideas

Answer (score 0):

Ion Auth code is really clean and organized.

You can easily hack the login process to accept both username or email. Even better, you can fork the repo on GitHub and make the $config['identity'] variable accept both string or array, and act according to that. And send a pull request! :-)

Regarding meta data for users: I would definitely use a single table to handle users metadata. You can put several columns and set to null in case some user type doesn't need them.

Hope my ideas help! Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem as you. And i found codeigniter authentication library alternative that could solve the problem. [Flexi Auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/user_guide/user_account_config#custom_user_tables) seems can handle "multiple extra meta table" for different user groups.