# Best Practices: Creating a simple CRUD web application with users/roles

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

After searching online a good amount, I couldn't find anything that was exactly what I was looking for or that outlined how to create a web application with users. The closest thing I could find was [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395278/best-practice-on-users-roles-on-sql-server-for-a-web-application), which outlined how to create a web application with users/roles on a SQL server.

I also found a couple alternatives from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240059/create-user-roles-and-profiles-in-codeigniter-using-ion-auth).

- Create a simple relational database
- make a 'meta-table'

I'm creating a web application on CodeIgniter that is a wine management tool, similar to [CellarTracker](http://www.cellartracker.com/). Each user has their own 'cellar', or collection of wines that they can perform the CRUD operations on. What would be a conventional way to make this. How should I structure the database? Are there any CI Libraries that would make User-management, roles, permissions, etc. easier? 
(I have already found that TankAuth seems like its the best authentication library).

Here's how I would structure (part of) the database:

```
**users_table**
id
email
password

**wines_table**
id
user_id
```

My plan is to have each bottle of wine have a user's id associated with it. I doubt that this is the most secure or efficient way to handle a CRUD web application with many users though.

I have experience with the CRUD operations, but am not sure how I can connect them with a user-management system.

Comment: That's all right. This is the structure you need. And it's safe :)

Comment: also check out Ion Auth for your auth library. otherwise spend some time building in CI before checking out libraries. figure out your requirements first. many libraries add way too many dependencies. you end up coding to the library which is not productive.

Comment: You could look at PHP Code Generator at ww.thephpcode.com where you can generate CI website matching with your requiremenet like CRUD + User access with role based permission.

Comment: @cartalot Thanks for recommending Ion Auth, I like it a lot.

Comment: also check out my Auth libary https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider having a completely separate table just for wines that is not associated with users.

this table has wine parents and children. the parent contains fields for the winery, the name of the wine, location, etc. the children would be the specific years of the vintage.

so a user enters a wine name in his tracker. the system looks it up - if its not found then the user creates the record. system creates a parent record and a separate child record with the year.

if the wine is found - then the user can update the parent record, and either chose a year, or enter a new one.

system would then add a record to a separate table - users_wines - with the id of the parent (the wine) and the id of the child (the specific year)

this opens up many different possibilities including having wine lists that are shared by groups of users.

you also can easily change the relationship of the user and his wine bottle - because they are separate. the user can change status on users_wines - wine in cellar, drinking the wine, empty wine bottle - and this does not affect the record for the wine itself.

====
Edit - yeah mentioning the wine.com api would have been good info. that gets into much larger questions. suggest that you **first define what your users are able to do**. My first question is - what if a user does not like the name coming back from wine.com? and what if there is an actual mistake in the api? **are you going to customer service a wrong wine name coming back from the api?**

Or - Can a user rename a wine in their list? if they can then the data relationship with wine.com is going to be very different.

personally i would think it would be annoying to try and create a wine list, but you cant edit the names. it seems like thats removing too much control from the user.

however if this is an app for restaurants that need accountability - then having the wine name be unchangeable could be considered a feature.

so **spend some time with your user roles and user stories**. then let that inform the data relationships.

Comment: Because I'm using the wine.com API, I don't think this would work. I would only need the product id for a wine. How do you think I should structure the database if each user should have their own wine list? Should the wine list just reference the product id or be safe and get all the info from the API and put it into DB (maybe update it every week or so)?